# Chained generic type inferred closures in swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am struggling to conceptualise in my head how to create a generic interface or class which functions
 like so.

```
 functionOne {
    return "123"
 }
 .chainedFunction { string -> Int in
    return Int(string) + 456
 }
 .anotherChain {
    [NSNumber($0), String($0)]
 }
 .lastInTheChain {
     print("value 1: \($0[0])")
     print("value 2: \($0[1])")
 }
```

so for this to work it is essentially an array of functions that pipe its return value into the
 next function's parameter list.

assuming each function closure was named after the function it came from
 i.e

```
 functionOne(_ functionOne:(T) -> T) {}
 chainedFunction(_ chainedFunction:(T) -> T) {}
```

then you would then call them like so to make sure you pass the correct values through.

`lastInTheChain(anotherChain(chainedFunction(functionOne())))`

The part i struggly mostly with is the Generics part and whether type inference will work or not
 (this is a secondary concern, would just be nice if it worked)

Im also attempting to use protocols, and generic protocols in swift require the use of thunks here and there which is only compounding my confusion.

So anyone out there a tad more knowledgeable if you would not mind chipping in how i could do this or whether it is doable in the first place i would be most appreciative.

Comment: `(T) -> T` is forced the parameter and return type to be equivalent. This is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functionOne` needs to return something that has a `chainedFunction` instance method, which itself needs to return something that has an `anotherChain` instance method, and so on. For this, you need to create a type. I'll call it wrapper because I don't know your use case, but you should name it something more meaningful.

```
import Foundation

struct Wrapper<T> {
    let value: T

    // This replaces `function1`
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }

    func chainedFunction<R>(_ transform: (T) -> R) -> Wrapper<R> {
        return Wrapper<R>(transform(self.value))
    }

    func anotherChain<R>(_ transform: (T) -> R) -> Wrapper<R> {
        return Wrapper<R>(transform(self.value))
    }

    func lastInTheChain<R>(_ transform: (T) -> R) -> R {
        return transform(self.value)
    }
}

 Wrapper("123")
 .chainedFunction { string -> Int in
    return Int(string)! + 456
 }
 .anotherChain {
    [NSNumber(value: $0), String($0)]
 }
 .lastInTheChain {
     print("value 1: \($0[0])")
     print("value 2: \($0[1])")
 }
```

Terminology: this `Wrapper` type is called a `functor`, because it defines a `map` method (here called `chainedFunction` and `anotherChain`, which are equivalent functions in the example). Using `map`, a closure which can be used to transform `T` to `R` (transform) can be used to transform a `Wrapper<T>` into a `Wrapper<R>`.

Comment: I had just come up with my own solution as i saw your reply, but your's is a tad simpler than what i went with and possibly a bit more performant. Good explanation though, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious, what did you come up with? For one, this syntax you had `lastInTheChain(anotherChain(chainedFunction(functionOne())))` would imply that  when e.g. `chainedFunction` is called with a closure, it stores it in a variable that's also called `chainedFunction`, that's later what's called in that long expression. That sounds messy. Also, it would limit you to alwas having an expressino of the form `lastInTheChain(anotherChain(chainedFunction(functionOne())))`, which means you could never write a chain that behaved like `lastInTheChain(chainedFunction(functionOne()))`